# Tooltips for the netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, ide

How do I get tooltip help from Netbeans 7.3?
And side-by-side dropdown boxes which divert me to the correct classes and methods?
Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 3):

You can get tooltip help from the IDE by hovering a line that has some sort of light bulb on the left of your code like below:

[image]

Then Pressing `Alt-Enter` the IDE will give you a list of suggestions of how you can improve/modify your code.

Also you can get the auto complete functionality by pressing `CTRL+SPACE` in the code editor. This will bring up any javadoc information about the Method/Object/etc like below:

[image]

Comment: Coming from Eclipse, overall I do kinda like NB, but the lack of a simple tooltip which shows method parameters when you hover over a call or constructor is really killing me.  If you're writing the code, CTRL+SPACE works great, but if you're just reading someone else's code (which is always more challenging) I wish there was an easier way to understand what parameters they're passing in.